# Find equivalence classes of $\sim$ on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations

Find equivalence classes of $\sim$ on $\mathbb{Z},\;\; m \sim n \iff |m-3|=|n-3|$.

I tried to write absolute values as:  $n=6-m, \; n = m.\;$ For, $m=0$ we have $n=6$ so we can say $0 \sim 6$, but I cannot make it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also $3 \sim 3$ and $4 \sim 4,...$

Comment: Are there any easier way to find the classes ?

Comment: And $2\sim 4$ and $7\sim -1$ and so on. So do you see what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equality $|m-3|=|n-3|$ means that one of the following possibilities takes place:

- $m-3=n-3$;
- $m-3=-(n-3)$.

In the first case, you have $n=m$, whereas in the second case you have $n=6-m$.

Comment: Yes, as I solved. But I want to know whether we have easier solution

Comment: For instance $[-1] = \{-1, 7\}, \quad [0]=\{0,6\}, ...$ is it?

Comment: Yes. That's what I got: $[m]=\{m,6-m\}$, right?!

Comment: Thanks a lot sir!

Comment: Who downvoted? It was very useful for me. Sorry for delay

Comment: It is easy to see for m = 3. Set rules